# mongodb query filter documents by array value or size

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document that's look like this if it hasn't got any items in the `itemList` field:

```json
    {
       "_id":{
          "$oid":"62e12a0b73a8c3469e635d93"
       },
       "listName":"name of list",
       "alloweUidList":[
          {
             "uid":"prQUKkIxljVqbHlCKah7T1Rh7l22",
             "role":"creator",
             "boolId": 1,
          }
       ],
       "itemList":[
       ],
       "crDate":"2022-07-27 14:05",
       "modDate":"2022-07-27 14:05",
       "boolId":1
    }
```

and looks like this if i have some elements in the `itemList` field:

```json
    {
       "_id":{
          "$oid":"62e12a0b73a8c3469e635d93"
       },
       "listName":"Kuli Gábor listája nr: 1",
       "alloweUidList":[
          {
             "uid":"prQUKkIxljVqbHlCKah7T1Rh7l22",
             "role":"creator",
             "boolId": 1,
          }
       ],
       "itemList":[
          {
             "itemDetail":{
                "itemName":"item 1 name",
                "price":459,
             },
             "crDate":"2022-07-27 14:13",
             "checkFlag":0,
             "boolId":1,
             "volume":1,
             "modDate":null
          },
          {
             "itemDetail":{
                "itemName":"item 2 name",
                "price":169,
             },
             "crDate":"2022-07-27 14:15",
             "checkFlag":0,
             "boolId":0,
             "volume":1,
             "modDate":"2022-07-27 14:16"
          }
       ],
       "crDate":"2022-07-27 14:05",
       "modDate":"2022-07-27 14:05",
       "boolId":1
    }
```

I would like to find documents that has at least one element with `boolId: 1` in the `itemList` array or the `itemList` array is empty. This query works only if i have item in my array with `boolId: 1` but not works if the array is empty:

```js
    db.shoppingList.find(
      {
        "itemList.boolId": 1,
        "alloweUidList.uid": "prQUKkIxljVqbHlCKah7T1Rh7l22",
        "alloweUidList.boolId": 1,
        "boolId": 1
      },
      {
        listName: 1,
        alloweUidList: 1,
        crDate: 1,
        modDate: 1,
        boolId: 1,
        itemList: {
          $elemMatch: {
            $or: [
              {boolId: 1},
              {itemList:{$exists:true,$eq:[]}}
            ]
          },
        },
      }
    )
```

Also tried: `{$size : 0}` thats not works either.

Update, I Forget. If I have elements with `boolId:1` and also with `boolId:0` in `itemList` i only want to return values that has `boolId:1` So if the document looks like this:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"62e1855473a8c3469e635d94"
   },
   "listName":"name of list",
   "alloweUidList":[
      {
         "uid":"prQUKkIxljVqbHlCKah7T1Rh7l22",
         "role":"creator",
         "boolId":1,
      }
   ],
   "itemList":[
      {
         "itemDetail":{
            "itemName":"item name 1",
            "price":459,
         },
         "crDate":"2022-07-27 20:35",
         "checkFlag":0,
         "boolId":1,
         "volume":1,
         "modDate":null
      },
      {
         "itemDetail":{
            "itemName":"item name 2",
            "price":549,
         },
         "crDate":"2022-07-27 20:35",
         "checkFlag":0,
         "boolId":0,
         "volume":1,
         "modDate":"2022-07-27 20:35"
      }
   ],
   "crDate":"2022-07-27 20:34",
   "modDate":"2022-07-27 20:34",
   "boolId":1
}
```

I would like to get this:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"62e1855473a8c3469e635d94"
   },
   "listName":"name of list",
   "alloweUidList":[
      {
         "uid":"prQUKkIxljVqbHlCKah7T1Rh7l22",
         "role":"creator",
         "boolId":1,
      }
   ],
   "itemList":[
      {
         "itemDetail":{
            "itemName":"item name 1",
            "price":459,
         },
         "crDate":"2022-07-27 20:35",
         "checkFlag":0,
         "boolId":1,
         "volume":1,
         "modDate":null
      }
   ],
   "crDate":"2022-07-27 20:34",
   "modDate":"2022-07-27 20:34",
   "boolId":1
}
```

And if the `itemList` array is empty i would return the document with empty `itemList` array

clarification: if the document has only boolId:0 entries, the query should return the document with empty itemList array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an `$or` in `$expr` to cater to the 2 criteria.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "alloweUidList.uid": "prQUKkIxljVqbHlCKah7T1Rh7l22",
      "alloweUidList.boolId": 1,
      "boolId": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          // itemList is empty array
          {
            $eq: [
              "$itemList",
              []
            ]
          },
          // itemList has more than 1 boolId:1 elem
          {
            $gt: [
              {
                $size: {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$itemList",
                    "as": "i",
                    "cond": {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$i.boolId",
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "itemList": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$itemList",
          "as": "i",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$i.boolId",
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/poijICRkmsq) for your reference.

Comment: Hi, this would be nice, but the boolId:0 item shouldn’t be present in the itemList, how can I filter it out? Summarized: itemList should be full empty, or should contain boolId:1 items. Thank you!

Comment: @solarenqu updated the answer. Just adding one `$addFields` stage for the cosmetic purpose.

Comment: Thanks its look nice but can you help me, where to put these filters: {
        "alloweUidList.uid": "prQUKkIxljVqbHlCKah7T1Rh7l22",
        "alloweUidList.boolId": 1,
        "boolId": 1
      }

Comment: @solarenqu updated the answer. You can just put another `$match` stage for your other criteria for simplicity.

Comment: thank you, it is almost good, but it's not returning any document if the itemList array only has boolId:0 items.. :( (sorry my question might not be clear enough) so if the alloweUidList.boolId : 1 for the specific uid it should return the document and items in the itemList with boolId:1 should be also present and if the itemList has only boolId : 0 the query should return an empty array.. is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: @solarenqu it is because your last 2 criteria doesn't match with your given sample data. By removing those 2 criteria and leave it to be handled by the `$expr` section like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SmZTVv7NTll), that could be what you are looking for. But I think that needs more clarification from you to know what you truly want. Nevertheless, the trick would be similar, it is just adjusting the criteria in the first `$match`, you may want to have a try yourself first before updating here.

Comment: Check this please: mongoplayground.net/p/KYEoaep3PP4 I changed the itemList items boolId fields to 0 and the query only return the first document but it should return the second document also with empty itemList array. Can you check it? Thank you!

Comment: @solarenqu it is returning the document with empty itemList array. Another document with all boolId: 0 array entries are left out as expected. It seems its working according to your current given logic.

Comment: Could you please modify the query to return the second document also with empty array? The logic behind this the boolId:0 items are invalidated so the document should be returned with empty array. I’ll modify my question. Thank you!

Comment: i think i solved: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VpGLXh8YJIg

Answer (score 0):

1. Shouldn't do filtering for *at least one element with boolId: 1 in the itemList array or the itemList array is empty* in the projection.
2. This `"alloweUidList.boolId": 1` search criteria will lead to no document is returned as the attached documents do not contain `alloweUidList.boolId` property.
3. Use `$expr` operator to use the aggregation operators.

```
db.shoppingList.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$itemList",
                  []
                ]
              },
              []
            ]
          },
          {
            $in: [
              1,
              "$itemList.boolId"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        $in: [
          "prQUKkIxljVqbHlCKah7T1Rh7l22",
          "$alloweUidList.uid"
        ]
      },
      {
        $in: [
          1,
          "$alloweUidList.boolId"
        ]
      },
      {
        $eq: [
          "$boolId",
          1
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  listName: 1,
  alloweUidList: 1,
  crDate: 1,
  modDate: 1,
  boolId: 1,
  itemList: 1
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xqfY1S0zrcZ)

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo, allowedUserList always have boolId property

Comment: Can you please check my updates in the question? Thank you!

Comment: just added this, to the end of your query: itemList: {
      $elemMatch: {
        boolId: 1,
        itemList: {
                $size: 0}
      },
    } this works, if i have at least on boolId:1 item in my itemList, but if i have an empty itemList array it's not returns an empty array..

Comment: Check this please: https://mongoplayground.net/p/KYEoaep3PP4 I changed the itemList items boolId fields to 0 and the query only return the first document but it should return the second document also with empty itemList array. Can you check it? Thank you!

Comment: That is due to for the second `$match` stage, the `$filter` operator filters the document with `{ boolId: 1 }` in the `itemList` array and return the array size. For the second document, it will return 0 as the array size which is not matched with the filtered condition and thus it is not selected. And this requirement is based on your original requirement.